# Loading en_core_web_sm results in AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'BertTokenizerFast'

Tags: python, pip, nlp, anaconda, spacy

I (a beginner at programming and anything pc related) am clueless how to solve the following problem:

I had spacy 3.7.2 installed, including en_core_web_sm. Running the code

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

resulted in the traceback mentioned in the title question.

I tried downgrading spacy to version 3.6.1 (via pip install), then ran the code again and got the traceback:

```
RegistryError: [E892] Unknown function registry: 'vectors'. Available names: architectures, augmenters, batchers, callbacks, cli, datasets, displacy_colors, factories, initializers, languages, layers, lemmatizers, loggers, lookups, losses, misc, models, ops, optimizers, readers, schedules, scorers, tokenizers
```

Same happend with spacy version 3.6.0.

Some other person ran my code with spacy 3.4.3 and that worked. So tried downgrading spacy to that, but got the AttributeError again.

I noticed, that on my PC (windows) under `...anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` there were still folders with en_core_web_sm version 3.7.2 (despite the downgrading). I randomly deleted those folders.
Then installed `spacy` again, and also tried to manually install en_core_web_sm with
`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-3.4.3`

But got the AttributeError in cmd. Tried installing different older/newer versions of `spacy` as well as en_core_web_sm but can't successfully install the latter.

So now I can't even load en_core_web_sm since it's not installed. Does anyone have an idea what else I could try to install en_core_web_sm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is older version of the `transformers` in your global environment that cause the problem.

To avoid version conflict, create a new virtual environment using [conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) :

```
 conda create -n myenv
```

Activate `myenv`:

```
conda activate myenv
```

install `scipy` check the [instalation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) page:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Download `en_core_web_sm` :

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Now you can run your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the step by step guide, that was really helpful! I could successfully install spacy and en_core_web_sm now!

But unfortunately, loading en_core_web_sm still doesn't work. I get the traceback [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'.
Could it have something to do with the path of the model?
I'm running the code in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code. In the traceback I can see the path: ...anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py:54

Comment: That great ! could you accept the answer to close the question

Comment: I edited my previous comment (I accidentally sent it before explaining that the code unfortunately still doesn't work). :)

Comment: you  may need to restart your runtime

Comment: After installing spacy, I closed + opend VS Code again and ran the code. Do you mean that? It still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Yes , did you activate `myenv` before running the code again?

Comment: I changed the kernel in VS Code to myenv (...anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe), but now it can't import numy and pandas (I have them installed via Anaconda). Do you have an idea how I could solve that?

Comment: you need to install the package you need in the new env, as it is isolated then the global env.